# PHP will include a file relative to a calling script, but not if the include path contains "../"

Tags: php, include, relative-path

From what I gather from PHP's documentation and from other posts here, PHP's include (and include_once) do the following:

> Files are included based on the file path given or, if none is given, the include_path specified. If the file isn't found in the include_path, include will finally check in the calling script's own directory and the current working directory before failing

I have the following structure in a given directory:

- index.php
- /dirA (contains a.php and b.php)
- /dirB (contains c.php)

From index.php  `include_once "dirA/a.php"`

Here's what works from within a.php:

`include_once "b.php"`

`include_once "dirB/c.php"`

Here's what DOESN"T work from within a.php:

`include_once "b.php"`

`include_once "../dirB/c.php"`

The curious thing to me is that b.php is included relative to the "calling script's own directory" but c.php is only considered relative to the current working directory (which is the dir containing index.php).  This seems to be a slight inconsistency to me.  PHP will include a file relative to a calling script, but not if the include path contains `../` - why?  **Why won't the `../` parent directory directive work relative to the calling script but it will relative to the current working directory?**  (note: I tested it relative to the cwd but didn't include that file in my example above just to keep it cleaner.  It worked just fine)

Can anyone shed some light as to why this is?  *Should* it work this way, or is this a bug?

Comment: Eh.  PHP's just odd sometimes.  I usually just add the app's root to `include_path` and specify everything relative to that.  Makes for less confusion in the long run, without sacrificing the ability to move stuff around.

Comment: looks like your comment may be as much as I'm going to get on this one.  If you make it an answer, I'll accept it...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

PHP's a bit odd in how it looks for files.  If you include a file whose name starts with a slash *or a dot*, PHP ignores the `include_path` entirely.  If a dot, it assumes the name is relative to the script that kicked off everything (ie: the one the web server decided to run).

If you want to specify a path relative to the included script and not the startup one, what you really want is an absolute include that specifies the full name of the file.  That's easy to do with the `__FILE__` and `__DIR__` constants, which reflect the name and directory of the currently running script.

```
include __DIR__ . '/../dirB/c.php';
```

If you like, you can also set the `include_path` config setting to include the root of the app, and just specify all filenames relative to that.

Comment: `__DIR__` looks good, but is it possible to combine `__DIR__` with parent directories? For example, how could we implement something like: `__DIR__.'../someFile.php'` ?

Comment: @GM: The example already shows how to do something very much like that. Basically the only thing you're missing is a slash before the `..`.

Comment: I'm not sure if that is supported on all versions php, because it didn't work for me. What did work for me, however, was something like `include (dirname(__file__,2).'/someFile.php'` Where `dirname` traverses up directories 'n' number of times, then you can concatenate that with your desired folder/file directory

Answer (score 0):

It is because you have first included the `dirA/a.php` to `index.php` , so from now on the `index.php` is your base file from which all includes are taking place. And therefore if you include `c.php`  from `a.php` it is like you do it from `index.php`

And that's why you are getting wrong results if you specify one level up with `"../"` . It searches one level above `index.php` and it finds nothing.

Comment: Thanks, but this doesn't quite answer my question.  If every include was *only* relative to index.php, then including "b.php" from a.php wouldn't work. (`include "b.php"` is relative to a.php)